# How to record video of screen in Windows 10 without Win+G?

Tags: video, screen-recorder

Windows 10 has a [feature to record videos](http://reviews.gizmodo.com/windows-10-is-hiding-a-great-video-capture-tool-1719196149), but it does not work if you don't have the proper hardware (which is my case).

How can I record videos of my screen (for free)? Basically, I want to play an Impress LibreOffice presentation containing custom animation in full screen and record it into an `.mp3` or `.avi` or any other common video format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're many software that can help you capturing a video for your screen in Windows, like *Microsoft Expression Encoder Screen Capture* and [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)

**Remarque** The second one is free, the first I don't remember any more ;)

Comment: Expression encoder is is free, CamStudio is blocked by Chrome as a potential threat

Answer (score 1):

You can try Open Broadcaster Software(OBS), which is used for streaming, but it also can do recordings.

Answer (score 0):

The highly recommended video recording tool for Windows is [iSkysoft iTube Studio](https://www.iskysoft.com/online-video/windows-10-video-recorder.html) for Windows (or you can also have iSkysoft iTube Studio for Mac version). It is a fast video recorder and allows you to record videos at 3X faster speed in high quality.